# how to add sharepoint search on non sharepoint site?

Tags: web-services

How to add people search on non sharepoint site. There is a departmental website (.net asp.net site) where that department wants to implement sp people search on their website. How would you accomplish this (thru web services)?

Comment: What version of SharePoint and which version of Search?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard search webservice that is delivered with sharepoint:
http://url/_vti_bin/search.asmx

create a separate scope that includes all people (content-class:SPSPeople)
and use that scope in the query that your define. Creating a query this way makes sure that only people are returned.